# Saving Google Colab Notebook on Github

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

[Checkpoints in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322072/checkpoints-in-google-colab)

In one of the answers to the above question it is mentioned that to save checkpoints in Google Colab we should push the notebbok to GitHub. I was having a doubt that whether pushing to Github will save all the files that are created in the VM environment of Google Colab Notebook. If no, please suggest an alternate solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Files in the VM environment will not be saved to Github. In order to save specific files, you'll need to write a script to save them either to your local machine via:

https://gist.github.com/korakot/e7f04fa7bd3a8a67b729da279ab1713a

Or you can save the files using the Colab Drive integrations:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/how-to-download-dynamic-files-created-during-work-on-google-colab